# Sum of json-formatted value

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a column that its value is JSON formatted:

```
Row 1: {"id":"1","name":"shoe","price":"1000"}
Row 2: {"id":"2","name":"bag","price":"2000"}
etc....
```

I want the sum of all prices in this JSON-formatted column. How can I achieve this? Note that I can use PHP to parse the JSON value, but the problem is that I should Group Concat all these rows (I want a single row). For example:

```
{"id":"1","name":"shoe","price":"1000"}||{"id":"2","name":"bag","price":"2000"}||...
```

`||` is the separator for example. My concern is that, suppose that we have 10,000 rows! Does MySQL support too long strings or is it even efficient to do so?

Is there any alternative ways to do this?

Comment: Checkout http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat and the `group_concat_max_len`

Comment: You are getting these rows JSON one by one from database query?

Comment: the acutal table has lots of columns for itself, but this column has a json formatted value and I need parsed values of this columns in a single column....

Comment: is there a reason why "name" and "price" aren't in a mysql table themselves?  storing and accessing json like this just screams bad database design....

Comment: The reason is these information are dynamic! I just gave an example id,name,price,.... there could be lots of other keys in here and they might change!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$json = '[{"id":"1","name":"shoe","price":"1000"} ,{"id":"2","name":"bag","price":"2000"}]'; // Assign Json to var

$jsonObj = json_decode($json); // Decode the JSON to OBJ

// Now loop and find the SUM
$total = 0;
foreach ($jsonObj as $item){
    $total =+ $item->price;
}

// Print the SUM
echo "Sum : $total";
```

Comment: Thanks Ashique.....I know this code, but my concern is a different thing: "suppose that we have 10,000 rows! Does MySQL support too long strings or is it even efficient to do so?"

Comment: What exactly you need, neither need to save JSON to DB nor find the SUM?

Comment: Doesn't matter anymore..I've used another way to do this...Thanks anyway :)